# Irrelevant value of k

Tags: c

The program is stuck in an infinite loop. I tried getting the value of k but it shows it as 854. Seems i have committed an error in the checktrue() function. Tried hours and hours. Not getting the problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
int checktrue(int *p);
int k;
long long int m;
void main()
{
long long int fir=1;
long long int pfir=0,n=0;
long long int sec=2;
long long int sum=fir;
clrscr();
while (n!=5)
{
sum=sum+sec;
pfir=fir;
fir=sec;
sec=sec+pfir;
n=checktrue(&sec);

}
printf("The sum is %llu",sum);
getch();
}
int checktrue(int *p)
{
k=0;
m=*p;
while(m!=0)
{
m=m/10;
k++;
}
return(k);
}
```

Comment: (1) `void main()` should be `int main(void)`. Discard any textbook that tells you to use `void main()`. (2) Please indent your code.

Comment: What is the expected and actual output?  What is this code actually supposed to do?

Comment: k is not initialized.

Comment: On what planet is the address of a `long long unsigned int` passable as `int*`? If your compiler didn't at-least *warn* you about that, throw it out and get a real toolchain (this looks like Turbo C, so that's probably not a bad idea regardless).

Comment: Please read the compiler diagnostic messages

Comment: I wonder how is it even possible to edit an answer as fast as @dbush did. I've been indenting the code almost since the the question'd been posted, but I only got almost halfway through it when the post was already marked as edited.

Comment: Also please don't use implicit int function return type, it is obsolete and deprecated.

Comment: @n.m. implicit int was removed in C99  . Also, `long long unsigned` was added in C99, so either way this program has issues

Comment: @ForceBru depends on your tools. Xcode, for example, will auto-indent  the entire source list on-paste, which frankly is the cat's whiskers.

Comment: @M.M afaik c99 deprecates it and c11 removes it completely.

Comment: @n.m. you might be right,  hard to search for since the standard doesn't explicitly mention it, it just comes out from the grammar rules for function declarations

Comment: @n.m. — I think you'll find C99 made it unsupported.  From the 'list of changes' section of the foreword to C99: — _remove implicit int … — remove implicit function declaration_

Comment: @JonathanLeffler yes you are right.

Comment: @n.m. Thanks. But still the sum is being printed as 0. The value is not getting checked.

Comment: @n.m. UPDATE-So after a few suggestions and a bit more nitpicking, the edited program works only for n<6, and as soon as i make it 6 or above, there is no output.

Comment: You are still not indenting your program, still using `void main`, and still not paying attention to the compiler diagnostics.

Comment: I tried using int main, but it still shows the same result, also the compilers says "suspicious pointer conversion" where i say n= checktrue(&sec);

Answer (score 1):

You pass a pointer to `sec`, that allows the function `checktrue()` to manipulate the input. If you get rid of it I get the output `15`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

unsigned long long checktrue(unsigned long long p);
int main()
{
  unsigned long long fir = 1, n = 0;
  unsigned long long sec = 2;
  unsigned long long sum = fir;
  while (n != 2) {
    sum = sum + sec;
    fir = sec;
    sec = sec + fir;
    n = checktrue(sec);
  }
  printf("The sum is %llu\n", sum);
  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

unsigned long long checktrue(unsigned long long p)
{
  unsigned long long k = 0;
  while (p != 0) {
    p /= 10;
    k++;
  }
  printf("Exited Succesfully %llu\n", k);
  return k;
}
```